# ImageView is not showing in Drawer?

Tags: android, xml, drawerlayout

I have simple DrawerLayout which contains some main content (they all display nicely), a navigation drawer which is only a RelativeLayout (id: drawerPane) and ListView (which I filled with BaseAdapter).

My goal is to insert some image above navigation items in the drawer. I tried inserting that image (from within drawerPane of course) by encapsulating it in LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, placing it on its own, but image is not showing.

How to insert that image in Drawer above navigation items?

Here is XML with short comments.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.ProfileActivity">


    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <!-- Add this, so AppBarLayout has a bug, which causes ViewPager not to show listview entirely on the screen
        Adding this view fixes (workaround) the problem -->
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center|top"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            >
            //Here I have bunch of small components which are displayed nicely 

        </LinearLayout>

        <!--Navigation drawer-->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/drawerPane"
            android:layout_gravity="start">

            <!--Profile box here-->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="start">

                <!--This is the image which I cannot place in the drawer. Busting my head for daaays.-->
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/welcome_logo"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/drawerList">

                </ImageView>
            </LinearLayout>



            <!-- List of Actions (pages) -->
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/drawerList"
                android:layout_width="280dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                android:background="#ffffffff" />


        </RelativeLayout>



    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Give that Profile box `<LinearLayout>` an `android:id`, and then add an `android:layout_below="@+id/your_profile_box_id"` attribute to the `<ListView>`. Alternatively, use a `<LinearLayout>` for the drawer, instead of a `<RelativeLayout>`, and it will automatically "stack" its children edge to edge, without overlap.

Comment: You are a saver Mike :)